# clear swipe push notification not work android

Tags: java, android, push-notification

I create push notifications. The problem happend when I use a cell phone with Android 9, the notifications are static and not clear when I swipe. This is my notification builder.

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(icono)
                .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent1))
                .setVibrate(new long[]{2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000})
                .setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000)
                .setContentTitle(Ititle)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentText(iBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOngoing(false)
                .setSound(soundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```